# Make 'git' assume I'm no longer changing anything

Tags: git

I'm working on Windows and commands like `git status` are slow on my medium-size repository.

I have finished implementing my feature (i.e. done with changes), and now I'm staging my changes (i.e. adding all the hunks relevant to the feature).

Can I make git use its cache for `git status` (and all other recursive lstat operations) and assume I'm not changing anything else?

P.S. I understand `git update-index --assume-unchanged` can be helpful somehow.

Comment: This may not be exactly what you're after, but `git status --untracked-files=no` is faster than a normal `git status`

Comment: `git status --untracked-files=no` still takes ~20 seconds, and even if `git gui` did that, it would still be tedious. Seriously, can't I tell git: "For a while, just trust me nothing new is being modified" ?

Comment: I doubt it's possible because you use git commands that require knowledge about the working directory. `git status` is supposed to show you changes, so it needs to look for them. You can only work around using git status. Adding hunks in patch mode obviously needs to look for changes too, but I guess you don't notice the delay there.